# Save program output to a (.txt) file

Tags: c#

My program

```
namespace trim2
  {
     class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
          {
            //ask user to start, if yes then continue, else then close

            DataConversion()
          }

    public static void DataConversion()
    {
        string lines = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\trim1.txt");
        string result;
        result = lines.Replace("- - ", string.Empty).Replace("+", string.Empty).....

         \\process goes here
         \\process goes here
         \\process goes here
    }
  }
}
```

What I expected is after the file goes thru the data conversion process it would save into a new text file (which is the processed one).. how can i achieve this?

Also, I tried this line, seems wont work

```
 File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Cleaned.txt", new string(ShiftLine));
```

Comment: Do not forget `@`: `@"C:\Users\Cleaned.txt"`

Comment: what error do you get in your program?

Comment: I don't see `ShiftLine` anywhere in your code, how is it initialized?

Comment: char[] ShiftLine = new char[0]; i erased the code @MongZhu

Comment: ok as long as you are sure that the desired data is in `ShiftLine` it seems ok, but still for the sake of completeness and traceability of thought it would be good also to post this part of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` character is used to designate an [escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

> Character combinations consisting of a backslash (\) followed by a letter or by a combination of digits are called "escape sequences." To represent a newline character, single quotation mark, or certain other characters in a character constant, you must use escape sequences. An escape sequence is regarded as a single character and is therefore valid as a character constant.

To avoid that interpretation of the string you either you need to write it twice:

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Cleaned.txt", new string(ShiftLine));
```

or you use the `@` operator to tell the compiler to interpret the string literally:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Cleaned.txt", new string(ShiftLine));
```

`@` is a [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim,

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you so much. BTW, is there any other method besides using these code?

Comment: @AliffM. please elaborate on "any other method". To write into a file? How exactly does you data look like? what is the desired outcome?

Comment: I mean, is there any other ways/code that i can write in my program to directly save the overwritten text file which have something similar function with this shiftline method?

Comment: @AliffM. Yes there are different methods. Have a look on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file). If this is not what you need, drop me a further comment